# 14.04 Dpkg Found kernel: /memtest86+.bin issue (freeze during update-grub)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Hopefully I'm not violating any rules by opening new topic for the issue I've encountered. Trust me, I've tried browsing all over askubuntu and bunch of other sites, but none of offered solutions have worked for me so far - hopefully you guys can help me solve the problem.

Earlier today I ran upgrade of my Ubuntu server to 14.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I'm having the following problem:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

If I run the command, its gets stuck at: Found kernel: `/memtest86+.bin`

Please advise how to proceed (I've tried multiple solutions including `update-grub`, and plenty others, but none worked).

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Setting up mdadm (3.2.5-5ubuntu4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
```

After restarting my pc and running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I'm back to the original issue:

```
Setting up mdadm (3.2.5-5ubuntu4) ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/mdadm-raid ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-grub is /usr/sbin/update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-server
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.28-11-server
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.27-14-server
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.24-24-server
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.22-16-server
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.22-14-server
Found kernel: /memtest86+.bin
```

`Uname -r` returns

```
3.13.0-24-generic
```

After a lot of trouble, solved by 
`dpkg --audit` and then `dpkg --configure <packagename>` for packages listed

Comment: post the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command.

Comment: comment edited per request

Comment: please post the above comment in your question.

Comment: restart you pc and then try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: post the output of `uname -r`

Comment: did as you suggested, edited my original post with results. thanks for helping me Avinash

Comment: For those with similar problems, please try the following: 'sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update' 'sudo apt-get -f install
'

Comment: @ftv3 so, that was the solution? Please post it as an answer to your own question

Comment: What's the output of `sudo os-prober`?

Answer (score 20):

This problem can happen in the case of Hyper-V virtualization (Happened to me today).

In this case the answer is to disable OS-probbing in grub by opening the configuration file :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And adding the line :

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

After saving your changes to /etc/default/grub, rebuild grub (running on Windows 10 Hyper-V with Ubuntu 15.04 VM):

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then apt-get update or whatev:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: @SalizarMarxx: Please don't leave "thank you" comments. Instead, vote for the answer if you like it.

Comment: Had the same problem on KVM, this solved the problem.

Comment: Had the same problem with an OpenStack VM, the solution worked nicely there as well.

Comment: Why didn't grub developer just add timeout for os probing which would print this advice?..

Answer (score 4):

> After a lot of trouble, solved by

```
dpkg --audit 
# and then 
dpkg --configure
# for packages listed
```

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I had Ubuntu installed on a Hyper-V VM and I had Enable Dynamic Memory checked (which is default).  As soon as I turned it off I no longer had the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04, which was upgraded from much earlier version (like Ubuntu 10.04).

Note: This is not a general solution, this is what worked for me.

The solution to this problem was to update grub from 0.97 to 2.

Details:

```
dpkg --audit
```

Showed a problem with mdadm, it cannot update with grub 0.97.

Here is the bug report:
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1285312