# Why is update-grub hanging, and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, 16.04, kernel

Every time I boot into Ubuntu 16.04 (I dual-boot with Windows 10), I've run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` to keep the Ubuntu side of things up-to-date.

Several times in the past month, the second command hangs with the following output (only the last few lines included):

> ```
> Generating grub configuration file ...
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
> Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
> Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
> ```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't seem to have any effect.

Looking around online, it seems this is related to `update-grub`. I decided to use `top` to see if anything interesting was happening, or if it was just stuck waiting for something that never seems to come. The only remarkable process was `mount.ntfs`, which was using 99-100% CPU.

This question is very similar to this one: [14.04 Dpkg Found kernel: /memtest86+.bin issue (freeze during update-grub)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455975/14-04-dpkg-found-kernel-memtest86-bin-issue-freeze-during-update-grub), and might even be a duplicate. In that question, the user was able to restart and audit/configure things via `dpkg`. (Is there a way to do this without restarting?) I've tried a similar thing, but my problem persists. I should not have to do that every couple days.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> `apt-get`, but suspending the process doesn't really help. Interestingly, while suspended, `mount.ntfs` still goes at about 100% CPU. I closed the file backup program in case that may have been what was invoking `mount.ntfs`, but it still uses about 100% CPU.

Hopefully I've provided enough detail here to make this question specific and sufficiently unique:

#### What might be going on here, and how might it be fixed?

Comment: I'm a little nervous to reboot if there's something wrong with Grub....

Comment: Can you get to recovery mode from GRUB? Can you still boot to Windows 10 from GRUB? The answers to these questions will determine what I suggest next.

Comment: I can still boot to everything. I'm just nervous, because I did something once to fix this problem (I forget what), and I wasn't able to boot into Windows. #PanicAttack

Comment: OK then, just to be safe, try this. Open a "FILES" manager (nautilus) window from the Dash, and in the left pane, click on the name of your Windows partition, and it SHOULD mount to the desktop... but I bet it won't. Report back. (Do you know how to run chkdsk in Windows?) (Do you know how to turn off FAST BOOT in Windows?)

Answer (score 4):

To fix the issue of the problem - os-prober - you can:

```
# vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to:**

1. kill `os-prober` process
2. run `sudo umount /var/lib/os-prober/mount`
3. run sudo `update-grub` again

Comment: Given that four years have passed since the question was asked, could you be a bit more specific about *why* this process might solve the problem? It could help others in the future 

Comment: @Matogo, no. Idk. But, I think, the problem is `/var/lib/os-prober/mount` is mounted and it cause a problem

Comment: The `umount` command itself hangs for me